# The non-generic type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, reflection

I read a private field via reflection:

```
var parameters = typeof(HqlProvider).GetField("paramList", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(query);
```

And it works fine. I can put in a breakpoint and see everything. But when I try to cast parameters to what it is (an ArrayList) I get `The non-generic type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' cannot be used with type arguments`.

How can it not cast it to the thing that it is?

Comment: Use the generic `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`... `ArrayList` is not generic.

Comment: Could you show the cast you are attempting?

Comment: Please show us the code that fails, not the code that works...

Comment: All of these fail: (ArrayList<QueryParameter>)parameters, (IList<QueryParameter>)parameters, (System.Collections.Generic.IList<QueryParameter>)parameters, (System.Collections.Generic.List<QueryParameter>)parameters. I am doing this in the watch window. Error for these casts are like: Cannot cast 'parameters' (which has an actual type of 'System.Collections.ArrayList') to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<FOO.DAL.QueryParameter>' System.Collections.Generic.IList<Foo.DAL.QueryParameter>

Comment: @dolphonebubleine Add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList` is not generic and implements no generic interfaces so you need to cast to the non-generic versions e.g.

```
var al = (ArrayList)parameters
var l = (System.Collections.IList)parameters
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. It wasn't working the watch window but when I put it in the actual code it worked fine.                var parameters = typeof(HqlProvider).GetField("paramList", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(query) as System.Collections.IList;